# Calculate the number of TP, FP, FN for the object detection task with many classes

Tags: python, object-detection, confusion-matrix, implementation

I am trying to count the number of True Positives (TP), False Positives (FP), and False Negatives (FN) for **object detection task with two classes**. I assumed that:

1. TP - is the detection with intersection over union (IoU) > threshold, same class and only the first detection of a given object
2. FP - is the number of all Predictions minus number of TP (FP = PRED - TP)
3. FN - is the number of not ground truths and should be equal to ALL_GTS - TP

Based on above I wrote the following method:

```
def detail_results(gts, model_pred,th):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    FN = 0
    GTS = 0
    PRED = 0

    for image_idx in range(len(gts)):
        gt = gts[image_idx]
        pred = model_pred[image_idx]
        GTS+=len(gt)
        PRED+= len(pred)
        ious = []
        iou_idxs = []
        for d_gt in gt:
            founded = False
            for d_pred in pred:
                iou = bb_intersection_over_union( d_pred[0:4],d_gt[0:4])
                if iou != 0.0:
                    # iou bigger than threshold, same class, not double detection
                    if iou >= th and d_gt[4] == d_pred[4] and not founded:
                        TP+=1
                        founded = True
            # GT than was not founded 
            if not founded:
                FN+=1
    FP = PRED - TP
    return GTS, PRED, TP, FP, FN
```

Where:

- *gts* contains Ground Truth Bounding Boxes in the following format: [x1, y1, w, h, class]
- *model_pred* contains my model predictions in the same format
- *th* is IoU Threshold
- Method *bb_intersection_over_union* calculates IoU of GT and
  prediction bounding boxes.

But results returned by this method are different than calculated by the embedded method from the [Darknet framework](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet):

[image]

Where I made a mistake?

Do you know some libraries that can calculate TP, FP, FN from bounding boxes coords?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand everything but it looks like there is confusion over what counts as an instance: does every image count as exactly one instance? In case an image can have a variable number of instances, I doubt it can be framed as binary classification. In the code it's weird that TP and FN are not counted at the same level. Normally at some point an instance is counted as one of the four categories.